# Meu PDF merge em python não está funcionando

Tags: python

Ele está mostrando erro na linha 3, diz que o arquivo não pode ser encontrado, mas eu verifiquei tudo certinho, oq pode ser?

```
import PyPDF2

f1 = open('documento1.pdf', 'rb')
f2 = open('documento2.pdf', 'rb')

pdf1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f1)
pdf2 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f2)

pdf1_pages = pdf1.getNumPages()
pdf2_pages = pdf2.getNumPages()

output_file = open('newpdf.pdf', 'wb')
writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter

for i in range(pdf1_pages):
    writer.addPage(pdf1.getPage(i))

for i in range(pdf2_pages):
    writer.addPag()e(pdf2.getPage(i))

writer.write(output_file)

f1.close()
f2.close()
output_file.close
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando o pgm Python gera um erro do tipo abaixo, significa que o arquivo não pode ser encontrado, ou seja, o arquivo não está onde o programa acha que está.

```
raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: nome-do-arquivo.txt not found.
```

imagine a estrutura abaixo:

```
projeto
   |
   +--- src
         |
         +--- meu-programa.py
         +--- um-arquivo.pdf
```

e `meu-programa.py` contenha

```
f = open('um-arquivo.pdf', 'rb')
f.close()
```

Caso o `meu-programa.py` seja executado dentro do diretório `projeto/src`, com o comando `python meu-programa.py`, ele rodará normalmente.

**Porém** caso ele seja executado de dentro de `projeto` com `python src/meu-programa.py` ele irá gerar o erro acima.

Sendo assim, dois caminhos para este exemplo:

1. Executar de dentro de `projeto/src`
2. Especificar o caminho absoluto do pdf conforme abaixo

```
f = open('/projeto/src/um-arquivo.pdf')
```

O método `path`, do módulo `os` ajuda bastante nesta questão de localização de arquivos e estrutura de diretórios com o . (Veja [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path))

Espero ter ajudado